# ADD_MONTHS sql query in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to implement the following SQL query

```
select SOURCE_SYSTEM,
       START_DATE,
       OWNER,
       SUMMARY,
       DETAIL 
  from CICUSTEXP.ACTIVITIES 
 where SOURCE_PARENT_ID = '001o0000006P8JH' 
   AND START_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1) 
 ORDER BY START_DATE DESC;
```

Here `STARTDATE` is of type `TIMESTAMP(6)`. Now I want to get data based on the months that I would be passing, if I want to have data for the last 3 months what should I be passing in here? Or if want to have data for the next 12 months starting from today what should I be passing from here. I am quite confused.

Update:
From the Conversations below I have the following query to fetch data for the next 12 months. Not sure if they are correct.

```
select SOURCE_SYSTEM,
       START_DATE,
       OWNER,SUMMARY,
       DETAIL 
  from CICUSTEXP.ACTIVITIES 
 where SOURCE_PARENT_ID = '001o0000006P8JH' 
   AND START_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 0) AND ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 12) 
 ORDER BY START_DATE DESC;
```

And for fetching data for the last 3 months I have the following query.

```
select SOURCE_SYSTEM,
       START_DATE,
       OWNER,SUMMARY,
       DETAIL 
  from CICUSTEXP.ACTIVITIES 
 where SOURCE_PARENT_ID = '001o0000006P8JH' 
   AND START_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3) AND ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 0) 
 ORDER BY START_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: "data from the next 12 months"? Do you know what *future* data will be?

Comment: The data is dynamic and not predictable. So i want to limit it for the next 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try with this:

```
select SOURCE_SYSTEM,
       START_DATE,
       OWNER,
       SUMMARY,
       DETAIL 
  from CICUSTEXP.ACTIVITIES 
 where SOURCE_PARENT_ID = '001o0000006P8JH' 
   AND START_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -n)
 ORDER BY START_DATE DESC;
```

In this way will be selected all rows with start date bigger than n month ago.

If you want select all rows until some month in the future:

```
AND START_DATE <= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, n)
```

Finally if you want all the rows between two dates

```
AND START_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -n) MONTH AND ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE ,n)
```